# How can i insert data from one table to another in symfony2 doctrine2

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I have table called

`tasks---id ,name,groupid`

`user----id,username , groupid`

Now i have another  table

`userTasks with fields id,name, taskid , userid`

Now i want that when the new user is created or persisted in database then

all the tasks with same groupid asuser should gets inserted in

`usertasks table with taskid and userid`

HOw can i do that

I am thinking of puting the logic in `postFlush() event`

But i don't know how doctrine first select and then insert the records in that table

Answer (score 1):

If your do it just after of insert the data, instead inside postFlush function, could be more confortable and easy.

```
$om->persist($user);
$om->persist($task);
$om->flush();

$usertask = new UserTask($id, $name, $user->getId(), $task->getId());
$om->flush();
```

$om is the ObjectManager; EntityManager is deprecated in Doctrine last version.

If you want to use postFlush() function, maybe have to declare both id's as private variables to have the info.

Comment: but i have around 50 tasks which want to bulk insert.asli which version they change em to om

Comment: If you have 50 tasks, maybe have to use for each () loop.
I do not know the exactly version, but in the last one is deprecated.